# External Web Server can't communicate with EC2 flask API

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, networking, amazon-ec2

I'm really out of my element here when it comes to networking.

I have an EC2 server running linux, which has an active flask API running.

I have a PHP function on a shared hostgator server:

```
function sendAPI($threadid, $teamid) {
    $url = "http://ec2-...amazonaws.com:9999/api2?id1=" . $teamid . "&thread=" . $threadid;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $optArray = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Similar function works without issue with the telegram API server:

```
function sendMessage($chatID, $messaggio, $token) {
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chatID;
    $url = $url . "&text=" . urlencode($messaggio);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $optArray = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

When navigating to `http://ec2-...amazonaws.com:9999/api2?id1=1&thread=1` from my own web browser, the API picks up the request successfully.

Inbound rules on EC2 instance:
[image: Server accepts SSH and API call from me, and accepts info from Telegram API servers. Should accept from external web server, but does not.]

Note, website IP, also the same IP is listed in CPanel:

> Domain Name: novociv.org Top Level Domain: ORG (Organization) DNS
>   Lookup IP Address: 108.167.142.88

From my limited knowledge of networking, this should all work correctly. However, when the PHP function is called it returns a null result and the EC2 server does not react. I don't know how to troubleshoot from here because I don't know where to find any error messages. I would guess that the EC2 is simply blocking traffic from the external server, but I don't know what's wrong (if anything) with my inbound rules since the EC2 successfully picks up requests from my laptop.

Comment: If you'll [temporarily] change the security group to allow 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to port 9999 - would request go through? It's not a secure solution to deploy, but at least you'll have an idea where your request is being blocked. Outbound IP for your PHP client might be different from the DNS lookup IP of the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that hostgator does not have port 9999 open by default. The problem can be solved by either requesting hostgator open port 9999 on this server, or else by moving the flask application to a different port which is already open.